# How Would I List All Google Container Registry Hostnames with the Cloud SDK?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-container-registry

How could I list all the different Google Container Registry (GCR) hostnames found within a given Google Cloud Platform (GCP) project using the Cloud SDK (`gcloud`)?

I.e., how would I list all the different GCR hostnames (e.g., `gcr.io`, `us.gcr.io`, etc..,.) for a GCP project `$GCP_PROJECT_ID`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are unable to use the `list` command underneath the `images` subgroup [and possibly apply filters or transforms] because it only lists repositories underneath the `gcr.io` hostname:

```sh
gcloud container images list

#=>

gcr.io/$GCP_PROJECT_ID/. . .
. . .
Only listing images in gcr.io/$GCP_PROJECT_ID. Use --repository to list images in other repositories.
```

Attempting to apply a wildcard (`*`) yields the following unfavorable results:

- ```sh
  gcloud container images list --repository="*.gcr.io"

  #=>

  ERROR: (gcloud.container.images.list) A Docker registry domain must be specified.
  ```
- ```sh
  gcloud container images list --repository="*.gcr.io/*"

  #=>

  ERROR: (gcloud.container.images.list) Invalid repository: *, must be at least 2 characters
  ```
- ```sh
  gcloud container images list --repository="*.gcr.io/**"

  #=>

  ERROR: (gcloud.container.images.list) Invalid repository: **, acceptable characters include: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789_-./
  ```
- ```sh
  gcloud container images list --repository="*.gcr.io/$GCP_PROJECT_ID"

  #=>

  ERROR: (gcloud.container.images.list) *.gcr.io/$GCP_PROJECT_ID is not in a supported registry.  Supported registries are ['gcr.io', 'us.gcr.io', . . ., 'mirror.gcr.io', 'k8s.gcr.io']
  ```

Trying to use the `list` command for the `services` group:

```sh
gcloud services list \
--filter="name=projects/$GCP_PROJECT_NUMBER/services/containerregistry.googleapis.com" \
--format=yaml \
--project=$GCP_PROJECT_ID
```

or the `search-all-resources` command for the `asset` group:

```sh
gcloud asset search-all-resources \
--format=yaml \
--filter="name=//serviceusage.googleapis.com/projects/$GCP_PROJECT_NUMBER/services/containerregistry.googleapis.com" \
--scope=projects/$GCP_PROJECT_ID
```

doesn't reveal any information about active hostnames either.

---

The only solution *seems* to be piping the output of the `list` command against the `asset` group into `uniq`:

```sh
gcloud asset list \
--filter="assetType=containerregistry.googleapis.com/Image" \
--format="value(name.split('/').slice(3, 4))" \
--project=$GCP_PROJECT_ID | uniq

#=>

gcr.io
us.gcr.io
. . .
mirror.gcr.io
k8s.gcr.io
```